# How to convert a PDF file with NodeJS + Unoconv

Tags: node.js, pyuno, unoconv

I need to convert a docx file to pdf but I don't know very well nodejs, however, I know that the following can be done:

There is a project called unoconv-worker and in it, there is a part where the following line appears:

```
  var child = spawn ('unoconv', [
    '--stdout',
    '--no-launch',
    '--format', job.outputExtension,
    job.tempPath
]);
```

https://github.com/koumoul-dev/unoconv-worker/blob/master/route.js

In my terminal I can convert it in the following way and it works perfectly:

```
unoconv -f pdf --output="something.pdf" docxtoconvert.docx
```

However, I would like to give you a file that I gave you the route, so I tried it this way:

```
var filePath = "/tmp/docxtoconvert.docx";
var child = spawn ("unoconv", [
  "-f",
  "pdf",
  "--output",
  "/tmp/something.pdf",
  filePath

]);
```

Output:

```
Unoconv converter received message on stderr function () {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    var result = this.utf8Slice(0, this.length);
  } else {
    var result = slowToString.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  if (result === undefined)
    throw new Error('toString failed');
  return result;
}
```

But it has not worked. Could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Try by giving the absolute path to  `unoconv`

Comment: The unoconv is in the environment variable. In fact, if I run the normal project, that is, as it is by default, it works correctly, without going through the absolute path of unoconv

Comment: yeah, but that's because you call it from your terminal session (I guess `bash`), whereas the nodejs session might not be configured the same way as the bash one. That's why I suggest you to try providing the full path to the unoconv in your script.

Comment: Same error, despite putting the full path of oneconv: 
Unoconv converter received message on stderr function () {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    var result = this.utf8Slice(0, this.length);
  } else {
    var result = slowToString.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  if (result === undefined)
    throw new Error('toString failed');
  return result;

Answer (score 0):

Lot of wrapper modules exists for unoconv that can solve your problem.

You can try this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/unoconv